# where is the error? -> mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, web-config, converters

I'm currently pretty in a delicate thing. 
I have written a .htaccess and via converted into web.config. a converter. Now is as always:

Internal Server Error 
The server internal error or misconfiguration Encountered on what and unable to complete your request.

Here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^housekeeping(|/)$ ./housekeeping/index.php
RewriteRule ^housekeeping/images/(.*)$ ./housekeeping/images/$1
RewriteRule ^housekeeping/faq/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ ./housekeeping/faq.php?do=$1&type=$2&id=$3
RewriteRule ^housekeeping/faq/(.*)/(.*)$ ./housekeeping/faq.php?do=$1&type=$2
RewriteRule ^housekeeping/faq/(.*)/(.*)$ ./housekeeping/faq.php?do=$1&type=$2
RewriteRule ^housekeeping/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ ./housekeeping/$1.php?do=$2&id=$3
RewriteRule ^housekeeping/(.*)/(.*)$ ./housekeeping/$1.php?do=$2
RewriteRule ^housekeeping/(.*)$ ./housekeeping/$1.php
```

Where is the error? ._.

Comment: Easiest to find out yourself is by commenting out one line after another and check when the error does _not_ occur any more. Then you have found the location of the error.

Comment: And certainly it makes sense to take a look into the http servers error log file. It will tell you what the problem is in there.